# Origin of the exclamation "Jeannie (Genie?) Martins"

Tags: origin-unknown, minced-oaths

My mother often uses the term "Jeannie Martins!" (or perhaps Genie Martins, I've never seen it written, though this seems less likely) as a general exclamation.

> Jeannie Martins, it's cold outside!

I've been unable to find the origins, so can any of you shed any light please?

I've asked my mother where it comes from, but she can offer little more than that my grandfather used to say it. He was born and raised in County Cork, Ireland in 1920 and  moved to North East England in the 1930s or 1940s if that helps any.

Comment: It's just a "minced oath" (euphemistically avoiding the potentially sacrilegious exclamatory ***Jesus!***). This particular one certainly isn't as common as, say ***Cheese and biscuits!*** (or ***Gordon Bennet!*** for ***God!***).

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Amen.  A case of simultaneous typing!

Comment: @FumbleFingers These seem like a bit more than just *minced oaths* - although I agree that they are them. *Bloody Hilda*, I suppose is to avoid the use of *Mary*. But how about *Blimey O'Reilly*?

Comment: @WS2: Perhaps you have a restrictive definition of "minced oath". In heathen UK today, I suspect hardly anyone who exclaims *Jeannie Martins!* (or uses *Bloody Hilda!* instead of *Bloody **Hell**!*) has any conscious awareness that by not taking the Lord's name in vain they might avoid spending eternity in the pit. I doubt many of them even factor in the possibility that *someone else* might be upset if they use the explicitly profane version. The "euphemistic" forms are really more about being *whimsical* than a serious attempt to avoid being sacrilegious.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Four syllables (sometimes three or five) are required to express incredulity in that way: *Gor-don Ben-net*; *Blood-y Phyl-lis* . There is exaggerated emphasis on syllables 1 and 3. That seems to me fundamental - *Blood-y Hell*. The format appears dictated by the phonetics. Surprise and amazement, for some reason, provoke *Bang-di-bang* and never *di bang bang* or *di bang di* or any other permutation.

Comment: @WS2: [Iambic rhythms come relatively naturally in English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iambic_pentameter) (an iambic foot is an unstressed syllable followed by a stressed syllable). On the other hand, the quintessentially *English* (as opposed to American) expression of disbelief is *Bollocks!* - which is a [trochee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trochee) (the reverse of an iamb).

Comment: @FumbleFingers But *Gordon Bennett* stresses syllables 1 and 3. according to Wiki an *iamb* stresses the second syllable.

Answer (score 4):

Although I wasn't familiar with the phrase until just now, it seems almost certainly to be a euphemism, such as might be found on http://phrases.org.uk under the heading **Minced Oaths**.

Like "Crikey," "Jiminy Cricket," "Cheese and Crackers," and "Jeezum Crow," it seems like a way to curse, albeit mildly, with either *Jesus Christ* or *Jesus and Mary*.

There are countless regional and cultural variations on maledictions made mild.

*I'm rather enamored of "Jeannie Martins" now, and may well remember her the next time I bash my thumb with a ball peen hammer.*

Comment: "Zounds, marry!"

Comment: Snails..Strewth!